# What happens to Realm database when the user updates the Android app from the store?

Tags: android, google-play, realm, realm-mobile-platform, android-update-app

I would like to know what happens with Realm when the user updates the Android app.
I have an Android application with some classes that extend from RealmObject. I use them to persist information on my app.
The thing is, when I define new classes as RealmObject, and I run the app directly from Android Studio, the app crashes: **The MyRealmClass class is missing from the schema for this Realm.**
I have to uninstall the previous version and then run the app to solve it.

**What happens when the user updates the app from Play Store and the new version has new Realm classes?**
**Would the app crash? If so, there is any way to solve it?**

Thank you!

Comment: `Would the app crash?` yes  `If so, there is any way to solve it?` either setting deleteIfMigrationNeeded(), or adding a migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the app would crash. You need to add a [RealmMigration](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmMigration.html) class.

```
public class CustomMigration implements RealmMigration {
   @Override
   public long migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
     RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

     if (oldVersion == 0) {
       // Migrate from v0 to v1

       schema.create("myNewTable"); // example

       oldVersion++;
     }

     if (oldVersion == 1) {
       // Migrate from v1 to v2
       oldVersion++;
     }

     if (oldVersion < newVersion) {
         throw new IllegalStateException(String.format(Locale.US, "Migration missing from v%d to v%d", oldVersion, newVersion));
     }
   }
 }
```

and

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
    .schemaVersion(2)
    .migration(new MyMigration())
    .build();

Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

// This will automatically trigger the migration if needed
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```